# Multiplying two 3d matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have two matrices `A` and `B` with dimensions `[a b c]` and `[b a c]` respectively. I would like to do the following:

```
C = zeros([a a c]);
for i = 1 : c
    C(:,:,i) = A(:,:,i) * B(:,:,i);
end
```

**without** using any `for` loop. In other words, via some in-built function, or maybe some kind of vector manipulation.

Is this possible?

Comment: I personally think the `for` loop is succinct and will probably perform quite well. What are your data sizes anyway?

Comment: a = 2, b = 32, c = 300. Not very big at all, I know, but I was interested in seeing if this was possible without a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your computation should already be reasonably fast. You could however try the [*`mtimesx`* submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support) by *James Tursa* on the File Exchange, that is described as:

> MTIMESX is a fast general purpose matrix and scalar multiply routine that has the following features:
>
> - Supports multi-dimensional (nD, n>2) arrays directly
> - [...]
> - Can meet or beat MATLAB for speed in most cases

---

If you are dealing with lots of matrices of small size, you might find that vectorizing different dimensions could also speed things up:

```
C = zeros(a,a,c);
for j = 1:size(A,2)
    C = C + bsxfun(@times, A(:,j,:), B(j,:,:));
end
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I'll take a look. Since my ultimate aim was to sum along the `c` dimension of `C` anyway, I realised after posting my question that I could simply reshape `A` to `[a b*c]`, `B` to `[b*c a]` and multiply the reshaped matrices.